# Autofill the answer of a question based on answer of previous question

Tags: qualtrics

Is it possible to autofill the answer of a question based on the answer of a previous question? I have uploaded a screenshot. For example, all the respondents who choose tennis as a favorite sport, the answer of the next question will be autofilled with 'Roger Federer', without answering the question. The question will appear to other respondents who did not choose tennis as a favorite sport

Thank you :)[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUcNc.png)